# jquery 3 document ready is blocking turbolinks from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks-5

I was using jQuery 1.12.4 so far and everything was ok, I had something like this :

```
$(document).ready ->

    console.log "document is ready yaay!"

    start = ->

        alert "Hello world!!!"

    document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', start)
```

I upgraded to Rails 5.1 yesterday and decided to add and upgrade my jQuery as well (yep I still need it) so I installed jQuery 3 using yarn, but the same code above doesn't get executed, at least the turbolinks part (the console.log is executed every time the document get loaded but the "start" method does not)

I removed the `$(document).ready ->` and the code start working as expected !!!

*To make sure I also removed jQuery 3 and installed jQuery 1.12 back and it worked! even with `$(document).ready ->`*

Why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add `//= require jquery` to your `application.js` file.

In the command line, run `yarn install jquery` all lower case

Here is my `application.js` file from one of my project using jquery through yarn.

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
```

EDIT:
If you want console.log and alert to fire at every page change. You can write your javascript like this.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  console.log('Test');
  alert("Hello world!!!");
});
```

Comment: I have no issue about adding jquery, I already have it in my application.js, the issue is with the jquery version, if you use jquery 3 and run my code it will only call the turbolinks method once, after that if you do multiple refresh the turbolinks method stops working

Comment: The jQuery ready event or this `$(document).ready ->` is in conflict with turbolink. I think there might be some namespacing issues where turbolink is overwritten by jquery or vice versa. Perhaps v1.12.4 works because the overlap with turbolink is not as bad. You can read more about it here https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads and here https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/turbolinks

Comment: I think so, it's weird, actually not using $(document).ready is the solution for jQuery 3